# Best way to model high score data in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I believe this would be easier with PostgreSQL or MongoDB, both of which I'm familiar with, but I'm using DynamoDB with my project for the sake of learning how to use it and getting comfortable with it. I've never used it before.

I want to use DynamoDB to store high scores for my typing test project. There are 4 data attributes to be stored:

- name (doesn't need to be unique)
- WPM
- number of errors
- test type (because I have 2 different kinds of typing tests)

At first, my partition key was testType, and my sort key was WPM. Then I realized that if anyone got the same WPM as a previous user, it would overwrite the previous user's data, because testType and WPM, the two key components, were identical. So ties did not work.

So, now, name is my partition key, and WPM is my sort key. In order to filter by testType, I just use JS array filter methods. This still doesn't seem optimal though for multiple reasons. For my small typing test project, I think it's ok, but I can see that it's possible for 2 people to input the same name and get the same WPM and overwrite each other.

What would be a better way to set this up with DynamoDB?

Comment: What are the access patterns your application needs to support?

Comment: There are really just 1-2. I have been doing it with one scan: I need the entries with the top 5 WPM and a particular testType, and also when a new entry is posted to the DB, I want an updated top 5 list plus the rank of the new entry if it wasn't in the top 5.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there's only one access pattern there: retrieve 5 highest WPM score items. I think the question should be rephrased with this access pattern in mind, as you ["you shouldn't start designing your schema for DynamoDB until you know the questions it will need to answer"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html), i.e. know your access patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the top X many WPM results for a given test type:

Set the partition key to be the test type. Set the sort key as `<WPM>#<username>`. Make sure to zero-pad the WPM so it’s always 3 digits even if the score is below 100. That keeps it numerically sorted.

With this key structure you have a sorted list (in the sort key) of all the scores for a given test type. You can Query against the test type and use `ScanIndexForward=false` to get descending high scores.

Notice how multiple identical scores by different usernames won’t overwrite each other. The username can be pulled from the returned sort key or from an attribute on the item, along with other metadata about the high score event.

If you have multiple users with the same username, well, that’s kinda weird. Presumably you have an internal identifier. You can use that as the suffix in the sort key instead of the username.